# How to Trace Ajax Call Back or Debug Ajax Requests in Chrome or any other Good and Famous Browser

Tags: ajax, ajax-request, web-developer-toolbar, chrome-app-developer-tool

I'm doing a project which ,obviously, uses Ajax to handle lots of requests from User Interface. Once of which is to "Filter" the given list of users. I'm using it with Laravel at back end.

So the scenario is that when I filter users by their company it works perfectly, but when I filter users by locations, it shows all the users from all locations instead of chosen location which means all the location ids are being passed. Code is written by some one else. I don't know where to fix it. So I want to know that Chrome supports some good tools to handle and debug Ajax request but don't know how to do that. Can some one plz suggest me the right way to handle, debug and explore the call backs of Aajx request so I could also save my time????????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the google chrome devTools console and go to the **Network** menu. It works great.

If you want more you can use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I've also asked about how to use or in other words "what is the best practice for using chrome devTools" to trace Ajax requests. Can plz add some thing more on this?

Comment: When you are in the Network menu you can click on your php file request. Normally you called the url parameter to Ajax and this is a php file. Then when you triggered your Ajax, your php file is in the left window of chrome DevTools. You can click on it and after you can see all the variables passed to your javascript. In you php file you can set some var_dump and you can see your var_dump in the network menu too.